# Image and counter not working with more than one counter

Tags: javascript

So I have this counter on my HTML page that goes up every time this 'thumps up' image is clicked, and when the 'thumbs down' image is clicked, the counter goes down. Max value is 10. This works fine. Like this:
**HTML**

```
   <img src="images/thumb-up.png" onclick="CountUp1();" id="votingup1" />
   <span id="counter1">0</span>
   <img src="images/thumb-down-dark.png" onclick="CountDown1();" id="votingdown1" />
```

**JavaScript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     var minVal = 0, maxVal = 10, clicks = 0,
  display = document.getElementById("counter1");

     function CountUp1() {
         clicks = Math.min(maxVal, clicks + 1);
         display.innerHTML = clicks;
     }

     function CountDown1() {
         clicks = Math.max(minVal, clicks - 1);
         display.innerHTML = clicks;
     }
     </script>
```

And that works fine!

So then I tried adding another section of this voting system. Have different function names obviously and different id's for the images and counter. Like this.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     var minVal = 0, maxVal = 10, clicks = 0,
     display = document.getElementById("counter2");

     function CountUp2() {
         clicks = Math.min(maxVal, clicks + 1);
         display.innerHTML = clicks;
     }

     function CountDown2() {
         clicks = Math.max(minVal, clicks - 1);
         display.innerHTML = clicks;
     }

</script>
```

But that didn't work. If I click thumbs up on the first one, the second counter increased. I did have this in one script, but it didnt work so then I put them in seperate script tags like above. I also tried calling the different variables, so for example

```
`<script type="text/javascript">
         var minVal2 = 0, maxVal2 = 10, clicks2 = 0,
         display = document.getElementById("counter2");

         function CountUp2() {
             clicks2 = Math.min(maxVal2, clicks2 + 1);
             display.innerHTML = clicks2;
         }

         function CountDown2() {
             clicks2 = Math.max(minVal2, clicks2 - 1);
             display.innerHTML = clicks2;
         }

    </script> `
```

but that doesn't seem to work either. I'm a bit stuck. Can anyone help. Thanks

edit: the second html is as followed:

```
 <img src="images/thumb-up.png" onclick="CountUp2();" id="votingup2" />
 <span id="counter2">0</span>
 <img src="images/thumb-down.png" onclick="CountDown2();" id="votingdown2" />
```

Comment: How did it not work when you tried the second option, to use differently named variables?

Comment: Can I see the html for the second part?

Comment: @MattCremeens  yea ill just add it. 1 min.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to move `display = document.getElementById("counter2");` into each function 
The assignment of display is done on page load, doesn't matter in two script sections or in a single one.

```
display = document.getElementById("counter1");
display = document.getElementById("counter2"); // overrides global
```

display variable, like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     var minVal2 = 0, maxVal2 = 10, clicks2 = 0,


     function CountUp2() {
         clicks2 = Math.min(maxVal2, clicks2 + 1);
         var display = document.getElementById("counter2");
         display.innerHTML = clicks2;
     }

     function CountDown2() {
         clicks2 = Math.max(minVal2, clicks2 - 1);
         var display = document.getElementById("counter2");
         display.innerHTML = clicks2;
     }

</script> `
```

Or use `display2` instead of `display` on the second counter.

Answer (score 0):

That's because these lines:

```
var minVal = 0, maxVal = 10, clicks = 0,
display = document.getElementById("counter1");
```

And also:

```
var minVal = 0, maxVal = 10, clicks = 0,
display = document.getElementById("counter2");
```

Are outside the functions, and thus global.. thus they overwrite each other. Perhaps Have only one version of each CountUp() and CountDown(), but allow a parameter that specifies the number of the counter.

Edit: I think you would have had it if you had also changed the display variable to display1 and display2.

Comment: nailed it!! thank you everyone who replied to me! I just needed to change the variable for the display the second time, by using display2. So now I have display1 and display2. 
and thanks for pointing out the second one overridded global. Im still learning.